# How would I go about making a completely new GUI for the Android OS or Linux OS?

Tags: android, linux, user-interface, operating-system, embedded-linux

I am getting into making my own embedded system and I wanted to use an open source OS to run on it but I can't seem to find any information for making a completely customized GUI (Meaning desktop Icons, Menus, and windows). Would anyone know how to go about doing this? Or could point me into the right direction to research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got quite a vague question there :

Here is [an article](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Porting-Android-to-a-new-device/) on how to port Android to an embedded system

> Information for making a completely customized GUI (Meaning desktop Icons, Menus, and windows)

You can start by learning android development.

Developers have full access to the same framework APIs used by the core applications. The application architecture is designed to simplify the reuse of components; any application can publish its capabilities and any other application may then make use of those capabilities (subject to security constraints enforced by the framework). This same mechanism allows components to be replaced by the user.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague but when I say custom GUI I mean the overall look and feel of the OS with the desktop environment or the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you picked out a development kit for this yet?  If you get a Beagleboard or something with a TI processor, there are great resources for getting started with Android or Linux.  The beagleboard would be a particularly good choice, due to a rather active community.

Freescale also has good support, particularly with its Linux builder LTIB.

I am not entirely familiar with how one would go about re-inventing a GUI for Android, but in Linux a good place to start might be with GTK+ or Qt libraries.

Comment: No I haven't picked a development kit, mostly because I wanted to design my own system and then port the OS to it.